# Search Within Files On Remote FTP Site

Tags: text, cygwin, grep, lftp

I am looking for a way to search within all files / directories on a remote ftp server for a certain line of text.

So far I am using `Cygwin` to make the ftp connection using `lftp`.
The furthest I've got is using the command:

> ls -l | grep pattern

...while in lftp mode.

However, that simply looks over the file names returned for the pattern.
I want to search within the files for the pattern.

Perhaps there is a software package that allows for this already.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: [FAR Manager](http://farmanager.com/) still does a pretty good job.

Answer (score 6):

You'd have to either have:

- an FTP client that would download all the content, and then searched it (*probably defeating the point*), or
- the server would have to have some extension that supported searching (*which I've never heard of*)

There are [some alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19291/is-there-an-ftp-client-gui-that-will-let-me-search-for-text-inside-files) over on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) that might help, but unless you can get `shell / SSH` access on the remote server, everything's going to be a variant of *download it all and search it locally*.